# How does the distribution of hash codes affect when Java's HashMap will rehash?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was going through [Rehashing process in hashmap or hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655239/rehashing-process-in-hashmap-or-hashtable/34238691#34238691)
which explains the beautiful concept of 
HashMap rehashing. 
I have a question about it.

Consider a case where initial capacity of HashMap is 16 and load factor is 0.75. Now, 12 elements are added to the HashMap, but they all end up in the same bucket due to a poor `hashCode` implementation.  The other 15 buckets do not contain any elements.  Will the HashMap rehash?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, at least with the current implementation of HashMap, collisions don't affect rehashing.  See, for example, [lines 661-662](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f#661) at the end of `HashMap.putVal`, which simply check

```
if (++size > threshold)
    resize();
```

where [threshold is (capacity * load factor)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#416), cached in a field for speed (avoiding a floating-point operation).

HashMap deals with overfull buckets [by converting the buckets from linked lists to balanced trees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30164087/3614835).

Comment: So, when will rehashing happen in this case? Total capacity is 16 and 12 elements are already added into one bucket (due to poor hash code implementation).

Comment: Rehashing will happen at 13 elements, because the threshold is 16 * .75 == 12.  But that has _nothing to do with buckets_!